# Migrating code and history from SVN into TFS 2012

Tags: migration, svnbridge

I have managed to setup SvnBridge v6.2 with TFS 2012. (Used this to make it work:[How to upgrade codeplex solution with reference to TFS2012 library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864204/how-to-upgrade-codeplex-solution-with-reference-to-tfs2012-library))

On Server PC we have installed TFS (server), SVN (servser) and IIS (on IIS SVNBridge is setup on port 8081).

On Client PC we have installed VS2010 (TFS) and Tortoise SVN.

Now I am following the SVNBridge website article which mentions that:

> Using TortoiseSVN, run a checkout using the following path:
>   `http://<yourwebserver>:8081/<TFSprojectname>`

I do the checkout on a folder in TortoiseSVN, enter URL Repository as

```
http://yourwebserver:8081/TFSprojectname
```

and choose the checkout-directory as: C:\test on my local PC. The code from the TFS 2012 along with the checked-out files has been copied to the above folder on the PC where I am performing the check-out.

Now I want the code which is being checked-out should go and sit into the TFS 2012.
I was told that we can use SVNBridge for code migration from SVN into TFS. So what is it that I am not doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not get the SVNBridge to do the migration of code from SVN into the TFS, I have used another tool (free) **SVN2TFS**:- http://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/

Now I have successfully migrated code from SVN along with revision history and folder structure into TFS2010.

I think now next step is to migrate from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 which should not be a difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.timelymigration.com/

Why Timely Migration?

Making the move to Team Foundation Server (TFS) can be a major undertaking and one of the most often overlooked tasks is deciding on how you are going to get your source into TFS. 
Only importing the tips of your codebase loses a wealth of information and functionality that is the true value of source control systems. Timely Migration is a suite of tools designed to be the complete solution for moving detailed history from your existing source control system.

Comment: The question is regarding SVN